# Rotate a linked list

Tags: c

I want to rotate a linked list that contains a number. 123 should be rotated to 231. The function created 23 but the last character stays empty, why?

```
typedef struct node node;  
struct node{
    char digit;
    node* p;
};

void rotate(node** head){

    node* walk= (*head);
    node* prev= (*head);
    char temp= walk->digit;

    while(walk->p!=NULL){

        walk->digit=walk->p->digit;

        walk= walk->p;
        }

    walk->digit=temp;
}
```

How I create the list:

```
node* convert_to_list(int num){ 
   node * curr, * head;

   int i=0,length=0; 

   char *arr=NULL;

   head = NULL;

   length =(int) log10(((double) num))+1;
   arr =(char*) malloc((length)*sizeof(char));          //allocate memory 

   sprintf (arr, "%d" ,num); //(num, buf, 10);

    for(i=length;i>=0;i--) {
      curr = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
      (curr)->digit =  arr[i];
      (curr)->p = head;
      head = curr;
   }

   curr = head;

   return curr;
}
```

Comment: Your rotate code seems to be moving the digits around, rather than relinking the list which I think the exercise was intended to require.  You get some marks for an equivalent solution, but it probably isn't the technique you were supposed to demonstrate.

Comment: You need to allocate one more byte - your `sprintf()` tramples beyond the allocated space.  Your length is 3 for the number 123; you need to allocate for a null terminator too.  You'll get away with it this time because `malloc()` will probably allocate a multiple of at least 8 bytes, but it is bad practice and you will get burned sooner or later if you do not allocate sufficient space.

Comment: But then I should be able to return a pointer to the new node. The rotate prototype has to be this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linked list actually has 4 elements.

You should change this line:

```
for(i = length; i >= 0 ; i--) {
```

to:

```
for(i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

because with the former line you're going out of the array (you're accessing `arr[length]` on the first iteration).

With this change your `rotate` function works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve most problems by breaking them down into simpler ones.

Here, I'd write your rotate as follows:

```
void rotate(node **list) {
    node *head = pop_head(list);
    push_at_end(list, head);
}

node *pop_head(node **list) {
    assert(*list);
    node *head = *list;
    *list = head->p;
    head->p = 0;
    return head;
}

void push_at_end(node **list, node *head) {
    node *end = get_end(*list);
    if (!end) {
        *list = head;
    } else {
        end->p = head;
    }
}

node *get_end(node *head) {
    node *last = 0;
    while (head) {
        last = head;
        head = head->p;
    }
    return last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your question is that the list is stored backwards, and you have a pointer to *previous*, instead *next*. This should have been part of the question (it took me a while to understand that).

Actually, you use *head* when probably *tail* would have been better. You should consider storing a pointer to the actual *head*, and avoid this way copying. In that case, you would only need to adjust pointers. If rotation is going to be a common task, then keeping and updating an extra pointer, may be in a **list** struct, would pay the effort (could change the task from O(n) to O(1)).

```
struct _list {
    node * tail;
    node * head;
};

typedef struct _list list;
```

In any case, the problem with your rotate function is that you are starting with walk and prev at the same node, head.

```
void rotate(node** head){
    node* walk= (*head);
    node* prev=(*head)->p;
    char temp= walk->digit;

    while(prev!=NULL){

        walk->digit=prev->digit;

        walk= prev;
        prev = prev->p;
    }

    walk->digit=temp;
}
```

Comment: What's 'backwards', or are you sure?  The last digit of the number (3) is stored in the last node because the construction loop counts down (indexes 2, 1, 0) not up (indexes 0, 1, 2) the formatted string - give or take the bug in the original.

Comment: Backwards means that the items are read from "last" to "first", specially taking into account that the head pointer points to the "last" element i.e., 3 or 2 in this example.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the code for linked list rotation by k nodes in c++. It worked for me perfectly. If you pass k as 1, it will rotate the liked list by 1 node and here it solves the given problem. If you want to rotate the linked list by k nodes, it will still work fine. Please find it below.

Header file :

```
public:
typedef struct node {

    int data;
    node *next; 

} *Node;

Node head;
void rotateByk(int k);
```

Following code is for .cpp file.

```
void DList::rotateByk(int k){
    Node current = head;
    Node kthNode;
    int count = 1;
    while(count<=k && current!=NULL){
        kthNode = current;
        current = current->next;
        count++;
    }

    Node kthNextNode = current;

    while(current->next!=NULL){
        current = current->next;
    }

    current->next = head;
    head = kthNextNode;
    kthNode->next = NULL;

    Node printNode = head;
    while(printNode!=NULL){
        cout << printNode->data << "\t";
        printNode = printNode->next;
    }  
}
```

Pass k as argument in main method for linked list d1.

```
d1.rotateByk(1);
```

Please let me know if you have any queries.